# Change in starting $n$-value for series tests

Tags: sequences-and-series

When does the starting $n$-value matter for series tests. For example, for the geometric series test, in my book it states the series as starting from $n=1$. If you wanted to apply the geometric series test starting from $n=0$, you would have to plug in $n+1$ for all $n$'s in $a_n$ to cancel out this effect. In other words, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(r)^{n-1}$ would have to be changed to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(r)^{n}$. However, for a test such as the alternating series test, you can apply it to $\sum_{n=5}^\infty (-1)^nb_n$ and also to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nb_n$. The change in starting index does not need to be accounted for by the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding convergence, changing the starting value of a series does not matter. For any $k$ and $k'$, the series $\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if the series $\sum_{n=k'}^\infty a_n$ converges.

Comment: One more question. For series tests, many say the sequence/sequences must be positive. By positive they always mean $\geq 0$ or just $>0$?